# Postgresql password and dokku

Tags: postgresql, deployment, dokku

My server configuration is using [dokku](https://github.com/progrium/dokku).

I wanted to update the server, and reboot it after a long time of operation.

After the server rebooted, the postgresql ip changed. I stupidly ran dokku postgresql:create to fix it (yes, i know it's stupid...), and now i keep getting the following error:
`FATAL: password authentication failed for user`.

I matched the password strings i have in: `/home/dokku/.postgresql/admin_pw` and in: `dokku config:set appname DATABASE_URL`, but with no success.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't have to create a new database for the app. If it's already been created, you should only see a response that database has been created.

This is achieved by

`dokku postgres:link app db`

Where `app` is the name of the app you wish to link and `db` is the name of the database you've previously created.

What will happen is the DATABASE_URL will be exposed in the app by an environment variable.

You'll also want to add [zero downtime deployment](http://progrium.viewdocs.io/dokku/application-deployment#zero-downtime-deploy)

Comment: Did not work for me, have app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/generic.rb:214:in `initialize': the scheme postgres does not accept registry part